# Storing solr data with amazon s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, solr, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I am using solr on amazon ec2, and I am hoping to configure the solr instance so that it automatically stores data in amazon s3 instead of anywhere on the server. However I couldn't find any useful information on how to implement this. Does anyone know how? If this can't be achieved using amazon s3, what cloud storage do you recommend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Solr.  How does it store it's index data?  Flat files? database?  The website says it is scalable.  How does it scale across multiple instances?

Comment: I'm new to solr either. As far as I know, it doesn't store flat files. As of scalability, I think it's because you can configure all the solr instances to use the same solr core.

Comment: I am also looking for the answer of this question, as i am unable to find configuration for the same, not even any useful link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to store the Solr indexes on an EBS volume, which you can attach to the server. S3 is meant for serving files directly out to the internet (such as images and css files), or for general file storage (such as backups.) It is not meant to be used as a mounted disk for a database.

Solr likes very high IO, so the SSD backed EBS volumes are great for this. You can also make snapshots of an EBS volume to backup its data.

If you setup Solr slaves, you can also get away with using the server's ephemeral storage. This is a large partition that comes with most instance types. It is volatile storage, meaning all of the data is lost if the server is shutdown. However, it is free and quite fast. It is perfect for a slave which replicates its data from a master Solr instance backed by EBS.

Comment: Hi Xevo. Could you tell me more details about this Solr slave you are talking about? I think this is the right solution for me, but I don't really understand....

Comment: Oh, I should also mention that AWS has their own search service called CloudSearch:

http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/

This service is based on Solr but is managed by Amazon. It doesn't support all of the advanced features that Solr does. However, it is great if your search needs aren't too complicated.

Comment: As for setting up slaves, this wiki page is what I used to set it up: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication

Comment: Solr 4.0 also supports a new replication type called SolrCloud (not to be confused with Amazon's CloudSearch!). This is now the feature that the Solr developers recommend using for replication. It is a bit more difficult to setup though:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrCloud